# Pressing a button in the same TR when return is pressed

Tags: jquery

I'm currently generating a form in a table layout but instead of using a table (Bootstrap issues), I'm using divs for the layout.

The general concept is `2 select boxes`, one is disabled.  When one of the boxes is selected, a JSON request is fired which returns a few rows of data - It may be up to 500 eventually hence why I'm trying to generate all of this dynamically.

This data is then used to populate the Div-Table and an edit button is generated in the far right column.

My problem is that I can't force the save button to be pressed when the user presses return.  Everything I've tried so far just clicks the first button that's found (because they all have the same name/ID.

The main part of this code is below;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select.changeLanguage , select.siteSection').change(function(){
        $("#tbody").empty();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Select.php',
                data: {LanguageSelectedDropdown: $('select.changeLanguage').val(), siteSection: $('select.siteSection').val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                $('#divid').show();  //Show the hidden div

                $.each(data, function (index, dbvalues) {
                    var eachrow = 
                           '<form id="languageset" class="tr" action="Update.php" method="POST">'
                         + '<div id="test" class="td">'
                         + dbvalues[0]
                         + '</div>'
                         +  '<div class="td2">'
                         + dbvalues[1]
                         + '</div>'                      
                         + '<div class="td2 test action"><button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="modify(this);">Edit</button></div>'
                $('#tbody').append(eachrow);
                });  // END EACH ROW FUNCTION                        
                     $('#siteSection').prop('disabled', false);  // remove the disabled marker against the siteSection dropdown 
            }  // END SUCCESS   
        });  // END AJAX
    });  // END CHANGE FUNCTION
}); // END DOCUMENT READY
```

All of this works as expected.   The net part of the code goes a little like this;

```
function modify(TheTableRow){
    var tr = jQuery(TheTableRow).parent().parent();
    if(!tr.hasClass("selected")) {
        tr.addClass("selected");
        tr.find("div.td2").each(function(){
            if(!jQuery(this).hasClass("action")){
                var value = jQuery(this).text();
                jQuery(this).text("");
                jQuery(this).append('<input id="new_value" type="text" value="'+value+'" />');      
            } else {
                jQuery(this).find("button").text("Save").removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-info');
            }
        }); 
    } else {    
        tr.removeClass("selected");
        tr.find("div.td2").each(function(){
            if(!jQuery(this).hasClass("action")){   

                var value = jQuery(this).find("#new_value").val();
                jQuery(this).text(value);
                jQuery(this).find("#new_value").remove();
                var POSTME = JSON.stringify({originalvalue: ($(this).closest('div.td2').prev('#test').text()), newvalue: (value)}); 

                     $(function () {
                          $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url: 'Update.php',
                            dataType : 'json',
                            data : {SuperSecret: POSTME}
                          });
                      });

            } else {            
                $(this).find("button").text("Saved").removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-success');   
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For clarity, this is all working as I wanted it to.  The user clicks the edit button, edits the row and then clicks 'save' to fire the JSON request (Which in turn updates the database).

What I want to do is let the user click return when they've finished typing instead of clicking save and have the correct button be clicked when this happens.

PreventDefault needs to be used as I never want the user to see the screen we're posting to but why doesn't this work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).closest('div.tr').find('button').click();
    }
  })
});
```

**EDIT**

Upon reading this a few times, I'm basically just trying to press the save button when the return is clicked...

HTML

```
<div class="table">     
    <div class="thead">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td">Website Value</div>
            <div class="td2">Translation</div>
            <div class="td1">Edit</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tbody" id="tbody">
    </div>
</div>
```

As the AJAX requests are a bit of a nightmare on jsfiddle, [here's the example](https://jsfiddle.net/jtn8az1o/5/) showing the (edited) generated source.

Comment: I've tried to follow up with you but i'm lost. Would you please edit your question and add a `snippet` ?

Comment: Perhaps adding some HTML as well to your question will help.

Comment: There's no html to add really as the form is generated by the code.  I'll add the hidden div anyway.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jtn8az1o/5

Comment: you should give each edit button a unique ID and the instead of  `$(this).closest('div.tr').find('button')`  just select `$(#+id)`

Comment: Whilst that would be an ideal solution @PA, the problem here is that the table is dynamically created.  A unique ID wouldn't be a problem, clicking the correct one would be though.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this as the use of a dynamic button would require a dynamic way of identifying the buttton.   Does anyone have any idea how this can be done?